# How to override Bronto Magento community extension?

Tags: magento-enterprise, overrides, magento-community

I'm having trouble overriding Bronto community extension (common module) on Magento. My custom classes are not being used, so I suspect there's something wrong with my configuration.

Here's what my shop/etc/modules/Bronto_All.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
    <Me_Bronto_Common>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Bronto_Common/>
        </depends>
    </Me_Bronto_Common>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Here's what my local/Me/Bronto/Common/etc/config.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Me_Bronto_Common>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Me_Bronto_Common>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <bronto_common>
          <rewrite>
              <email_template>Me_Bronto_Common_Model_Email_Template</email_template>
              <system_config_source_related>Me_Bronto_Common_Model_System_Config_Source_Related</system_config_source_related>
          </rewrite>
        </bronto_common>
    </models>
</global>
```

Here's what my local/Me/Bronto/Common/Model/Email/Template.php looks like:

```
<?php
class Me_Bronto_Common_Model_Email_Template extends Bronto_Common_Model_Email_Template
{
      public function send($email, $name = null, array $variables = array())
      {
        //some code
      }
}
```

Here's what my local/Me/Bronto/Common/Model/System/Config/Source/Related.php looks like:

```
<?php
class Me_Bronto_Common_Model_System_Config_Source_Related extends  Bronto_Common_Model_System_Config_Source_Related
{
      public function toOptionArray($isMultiselect = null)
     { 
      // some code
      }
}
```

Can anyone tell if something is wrong or missing from the configuration above? Thanks.

---

Here's the core Bronto config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
    <modules>
        <Bronto_Common>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </Bronto_Common>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <bronto_common>
            <class>Bronto_Common_Block</class>
        </bronto_common>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <bronto_common>
            <class>Bronto_Common_Helper</class>
        </bronto_common>
    </helpers>
    <models>
        <bronto_common>
            <class>Bronto_Common_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>bronto_common_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </bronto_common>
        <bronto_common_mysql4>
          <class>Bronto_Common_Model_Mysql4</class>
          <entities>
              <api>
                  <table>bronto_common_api</table>
              </api>
              <error>
                  <table>bronto_common_api_errors</table>
              </error>
              <queue>
                  <table>bronto_common_api_send_queue</table>
              </queue>
          </entities>
        </bronto_common_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <bronto_common_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Bronto_Common</module>
                <class>Bronto_Common_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </bronto_common_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <bronto_common>
                <file>bronto/common.xml</file>
            </bronto_common>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <routers>
        <bronto_common>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Bronto_Common</module>
                <frontName>bronto</frontName>
            </args>
        </bronto_common>
    </routers>
</frontend>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <bronto_common before="Mage_Adminhtml">Bronto_Common_Adminhtml</bronto_common>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <bronto_common>
                <file>bronto/common.xml</file>
            </bronto_common>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <events>
        <bronto_disable>
            <observers>
                <bronto_common_disable>
                    <class>bronto_common/observer</class>
                    <method>watchDisableAction</method>
                </bronto_common_disable>
            </observers>
        </bronto_disable>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                <bronto_common_controller_action_predispatch>
                    <class>bronto_common/observer</class>
                    <method>checkBrontoRequirements</method>
                </bronto_common_controller_action_predispatch>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
        <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml>
            <observers>
                <bronto_common_registration_form_submit>
                    <class>bronto_common/observer</class>
                    <method>registerExtension</method>
                </bronto_common_registration_form_submit>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
<default>
    <bronto>
        <settings>
            <enabled>1</enabled>
            <debug>1</debug>
            <log_threshold>30</log_threshold>
            <clear_logs>1</clear_logs>
            <verbose>0</verbose>
            <test>0</test>
            <notices>0</notices>
        </settings>
        <format>
            <image_type>small_image</image_type>
            <image_width>88</image_width>
            <image_height>77</image_height>
            <default_greeting>Valued Customer</default_greeting>
            <default_greeting_prefix></default_greeting_prefix>
            <default_greeting_firstname></default_greeting_firstname>
            <default_greeting_lastname></default_greeting_lastname>
        </format>
        <support>
            <registered>0</registered>
            <using_solution_partner>1</using_solution_partner>
        </support>
    </bronto>
    <bronto_popup>
        <settings>
            <subscribe>0</subscribe>
        </settings>
    </bronto_popup>
    <bronto_api>
        <settings>
            <enabled>0</enabled>
            <mage_cron>1</mage_cron>
            <frequency>I</frequency>
            <interval>5</interval>
            <minutes>0</minutes>
            <limit>50</limit>
            <threshold>5</threshold>
        </settings>
        <queue_settings>
            <enabled>0</enabled>
            <mage_cron>1</mage_cron>
            <frequency>I</frequency>
            <interval>5</interval>
            <minutes>0</minutes>
            <limit>50</limit>
        </queue_settings>
        <soap_options>
            <soap_client>Bronto_SoapClient</soap_client>
            <observer>Bronto_Common_Model_Api</observer>
            <retryer>Bronto_Common_Model_Error</retryer>
            <stream_context>0</stream_context>
            <retry_limit>2</retry_limit>
            <trace>0</trace>
            <exceptions>1</exceptions>
            <connection_timeout>30</connection_timeout>
            <cache_wsdl>WSDL_CACHE_BOTH</cache_wsdl>
        </soap_options>
    </bronto_api>
</default>
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <bronto_common_errors>
            <run>
                <model>bronto_common/observer::processApiErrors</model>
            </run>
        </bronto_common_errors>
        <bronto_common_queue>
            <run>
                <model>bronto_common/observer::processSendQueue</model>
            </run>
        </bronto_common_queue>
        <bronto_common_delete_archives>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>0 0 * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>bronto_common/observer::clearArchives</model>
            </run>
        </bronto_common_delete_archives>
        <bronto_common_delete_old_logs>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>0 0 * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>bronto_common/observer::clearOldLogs</model>
            </run>
        </bronto_common_delete_old_logs>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
<phpunit>
    <suite>
        <modules>
            <Bronto_Common/>
        </modules>
    </suite>
</phpunit>
</config>
```

Comment: Have you tried placing your files in `app/code/local/Me/BrontoCommon/` instead of `app/code/local/Me/Bronto/Common/`. I am not sure how Magento handles three-deep folders in modules. Everything I see and use is two-deep folders in modules.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Joseph. Just tried using a two-deep structure but still didn't work. Magento is still calling the community version.

Comment: Have you disabled all caches?

Comment: Yes, all caches are disabled on my local machine

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your naming convention

/etc/modules/Me_BrontoCommon.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
    <Me_BrontoCommon>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Bronto_Common/>
        </depends>
    </Me_BrontoCommon>
    </modules>
</config>
```

local/Me/BrontoCommon/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Me_BrontoCommon>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Me_BrontoCommon>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <mybrontocommon>
            <class>Me_BrontoCommon_Model</class>
        <brontocommon>
        <mybronto_common>
          <rewrite>
              <email_template>Me_BrontoCommon_Model_Email_Template</email_template>
              <system_config_source_related>Me_BrontoCommon_Model_System_Config_Source_Related</system_config_source_related>
          </rewrite>
        </bronto_common>
    </models>
</global>
```

Here's what my local/Me/BrontoCommon/Model/Email/Template.php

```
<?php
class Me_BrontoCommon_Model_Email_Template extends Bronto_Common_Model_Email_Template
{
      public function send($email, $name = null, array $variables = array())
      {
        //some code
      }
}
```

local/Me/BrontoCommon/Model/System/Config/Source/Related.php

```
<?php
class Me_BrontoCommon_Model_System_Config_Source_Related extends  Bronto_Common_Model_System_Config_Source_Related
{
      public function toOptionArray($isMultiselect = null)
     { 
      // some code
      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's still not working =(

Comment: Can you add the config.xml from Bronto

Comment: R.S. done (see above)

Comment: Check to make sure your module is enable in system -> config -> advance

Comment: Yes, they are enabled. Still not working though.